# How i can use two sum() with two different conditions?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

i have Table1 ,in this table users can charge their account

```
 userid       action       amount
   1          Deposit      10000
   1          removal      500
   2          Deposit      20000
   2          removal      13000
```

now i want take select remaine charge for every user.

Sum(amount)`with conditions WHERE action='Deposit'` - SUM(amount)`with conditions WHERE action='removal'`

now result code should be the following :

```
 userid       reamine charge
   1              9500
   2              7000
```

thanks alot

Comment: This would be much easier if you handled the data properly. If *deposit* is a positive number, and *removal* is a negative, then a simple SUM(amount) with a GROUP BY would give you a balance.

Comment: Your question is an [X/Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Tell us what problem you are trying to solve instead of asking for help with the solution, which does not appear to be the correct approach. **The correct solution is the one @KeyWhite suggests, fix your data.**

Comment: @JarrodRoberson While that is the right design, it is not always an option to make those changes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should sum only on particular filters.

```
SELECT
    userId,
    SUM(CASE WHEN action = 'deposit' THEN amount END) TotalDeposits,
    SUM(CASE WHEN action = 'removal' THEN amount END) TotalRemovals,
    SUM(CASE WHEN action = 'deposit' THEN amount END)
        - SUM(CASE WHEN action = 'removal' THEN amount END) TotalAvailable
FROM
    Table1
GROUP BY
    userId
```

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with the comment that you should be storing negatives, here is a solution.

```
DECLARE @data TABLE ([userid] int,[action] NVARCHAR(200),Amount MONEY)

INSERT INTO @data ([userid],[action],Amount) SELECT 1,'Deposit',10000
INSERT INTO @data ([userid],[action],Amount) SELECT 1,'removal',500
INSERT INTO @data ([userid],[action],Amount) SELECT 2,'Deposit',20000
INSERT INTO @data ([userid],[action],Amount) SELECT 2,'removal',13000

select
    [userid],
    sum (
        CASE
            WHEN [action]='Deposit' THEN Amount
            ELSE -1.0 * Amount
        END
    ) AS [reamine charge]
FROM @DATA
group by [userid]
```

Your requested solution is not the best, but here it is:

```
select
    [userid],
    (
       sum(CASE WHEN [action]='Deposit' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END)
       -sum(CASE WHEN [action]='removal' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END)
    ) AS [reamine charge]
FROM @DATA
group by [userid]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select client_id, credits,debits, credits-debits as balance
from (SELECT 
client_id,
SUM(case when ACTION_TYPE='Deposit' then action_amount else 0 end) AS credits, 
SUM(case when ACTION_TYPE='removal' then action_amount else 0 end) AS debits
FROM categories 
GROUP BY client_id) a
where debits-credits<>0;
```

Using SUM() can do your needs..
[Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2bf41/3)

Answer (score -1):

```
Here is another way to achive what u want, i will leave
```

a little bit more information in my statement so u can see what actually happen

```
SELECT ts.*, removal.*, 
SUM(ts.amount) as total_deposit, 
SUM(removal.amount) AS total_removal,  
SUM(ts.amount) - SUM(removal.amount) as result FROM Table1 as ts
INNER JOIN Table1 as removal ON ts.userId=removal.userId
WHERE ts.action = 'Deposit' AND removal.action='removal'
GROUP BY ts.userId, ts.action


and this is cleared variant of the statement

SELECT ts.userId,
SUM(ts.amount) - SUM(removal.amount) as result 
FROM Table1 as ts
INNER JOIN Table1 as removal ON ts.userId=removal.userId
WHERE ts.action = 'Deposit' AND removal.action='removal'
GROUP BY ts.userId, ts.action
```